# How are we finding the inverse of this subset of the unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, trigonometry

If $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is given by $x \mapsto (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2 \pi x))$, and $U= \{(a, b) \in S^1 : a > 0\}$, what is $p^{-1}(U)$?

It is written that the inverse is the union of all the open intervals $(n - \frac{1}{4}, n + \frac{1}{4}), n \in \Bbb{Z}.$ I can check by inspection that this is correct, but I don't know how do you mathematically/algebraically find this inverse?

Comment: You start with a preimage of a point. For that you need to solve equations $\cos(2\pi x)=\cos(2\pi y)$ and $\sin(2\pi x)=\sin(2\pi y)$. And then you can apply this to $U$ which is a set of points.

Comment: @freakish can you please explain in a little detail. I don't understand why I'm solving these equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of preimage set, $p^{-1}(U)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:p(x)\in U\}$, and statement $p(x)\in U$ is just equivalent to $\cos2\pi x>0$.

So what to do is to solve that inequality. Let $u=2\pi x$ and consider the new inequality $\cos u>0$. You may first restrict $u$ to be in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then the solution is $u\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. By periodicity of cosine function, the general solution is $u\in(2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}), n\in \mathbb{Z}$ . Plug $2\pi x$ back into $u$, we get the answer as stated.